# Return NSArray function from asynchronous BLOCK

Tags: objective-c, return, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I have a function that must have this signature and must return an array of Test objects

```
+ (NSArray <Test *>*_Nullable) getAllDetails
```

Within the function I am doing a GET request using RESTKIT asynchronously which fetches the data succesfully from a remote REST API and saving to an array which I return here. Because the function returns before the block has executed when I call the class somewhere else with `[MyClass getAllDetails];` function my array of Test objects is nil however when I log within the call the array is populated. Been a while i've done some OJB-C and blocks for that matter.

Comment: `+ (NSArray <Test *>*_Nullable) getAllDetails` => `+ (void) getAllDetails:(void (^)(NSArray <Test *>*_Nullable))block{ ... //at some point in your code: if (block){ block(someArrayConstructed);}}`. A few solutions is to create in a sample app a `URLSession.dataTask...` to remember the wording, or a array sort, etc.

Comment: How about defining a delegate function that will receive the `NSArray` when it is successfully populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wrong approach if you are fetching the data asynchronously you should use the block approach or create delegate method to handle the response.

You can try block approach like this

```
//Declare your block like this in your class
typedef void (^GetAllRequestBlock)(NSArray <Test *>*_Nullable);
```

And Use it in your function like :-

```
+ (void)getAllDetails:(GetAllRequestBlock)completionHandler{
    BOOL response = true; // Your api response check
    if (response) {
        if completionHandler{
            completionHandler(Array); // Pass your array custom array that you've defined in the block
        }
    }else{
        if completionHandler{
            completionHandler(nil);
        }
    }
}
```